# see the below code but getCoulmnName is not taking index i?help me

Tags: jdbc

```
package pack;

import java.sql.*;

class Rsmd {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.23.0.100:1521:esgdb10", "scott",
                    "tiger");

       PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from employee");
                        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            System.out.println                              ("Totalcolumns: "rsmd.getColumnCount ());
            int x = 0;
            x = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                System.out.println("Column Name of 1stcolumn: "+ rsmd.getColumnName(i));
System.out.println("Column Type Name of column: "
                        + rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i));/*here it is not taking index i */
 /* i want to display all the column name of a record*/
            }
            con.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

In the above code, used oracle driver and i wanted to display all column names of a record.for this i used index-i but the getColumnName is not supporting index-i.pls help me.

Comment: JDK version please? and what's the error that you see?

Answer (score 0):

[`ResultSetMetaData.getColumnName(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnName(int)) is **one**-based.

So your iteration should start at `1` and end at `getColumnCount()`, inclusive:

```
int x = rsmd.getColumnCount();
for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
    System.out.println("Column Name of 1stcolumn: " + rsmd.getColumnName(i));
    System.out.println("Column Type Name of column: " + rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i));
}
```

Comment: yah i got to know that.it has given the error invalid index.i think  index starts from 1 not with 0